# Bug with Banner->LoadAd(); function

Tags: c++, ads, c++builder-xe7, appmethod

I know I isn't exactly related to C++, but I'm having a little trouble when a call a function named LoadAd().
I've tried to use this function into a timer in OnTimer, in events like OnFormShow and OnFormCreate(Yes, I know it cant be in that function, but I tried). However the application always gets FC (Forced close) when executing this function... Are there any solution for that?

Here is part of my code:

```
void __fastcall TfrmPrincipal::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    // This defines the default active tab at runtime
    abasPrinc->ActiveTab = abaDisp;
    Auto = false;
    Manual = false;
    SEM_AD = false;

    ad1->AdUnitID = "SECRET";
    ad2->AdUnitID = "SECRET";

}
```

and:

```
void __fastcall TfrmPrincipal::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    ad1->LoadAd();
    ad2->LoadAd();
}
```

Declaraion (Principal.h)

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#ifndef PrincipalH
#define PrincipalH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Forms.hpp>
#include <FMX.ActnList.hpp>
#include <FMX.Gestures.hpp>
#include <FMX.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <FMX.TabControl.hpp>
#include <FMX.Types.hpp>
#include <System.Actions.hpp>
#include <FMX.ListView.hpp>
#include <FMX.ListView.Types.hpp>
#include <FMX.MultiView.hpp>
#include <FMX.Advertising.hpp>
#include <FMX.Layouts.hpp>
#include <FMX.ListBox.hpp>
#include <FMX.Objects.hpp>
#include <FMX.Memo.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TfrmPrincipal : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    /* ...  */

    TBannerAd *ad1;
    TBannerAd *ad2;

    /* ...  */

    void __fastcall FormCreate(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall FormKeyUp(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, System::WideChar &KeyChar,
          TShiftState Shift);

    /* ...  */

    void __fastcall FormShow(TObject *Sender);

    /* ...  */


private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TfrmPrincipal(TComponent* Owner);
    void adaptar();
    int Num(unsigned char caractere);
    void RedefInicio ();
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TfrmPrincipal *frmPrincipal;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Since now thanks A LOT.

Comment: What does "FC" mean? Segmentation fault? And how are ad1/ad2 declared?

Comment: FC means Forced Close...
I'll paste the declaration in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem...
I was using an old AndroidManifest.template (I began to build this app on XE6), so some declarations as ADMob are differents didn't worked.
To avoid situations like mine, is just needed to delete the oldest auto generated files...

XD